# Retrieving public tweets from twitter with Asynctask

Tags: android

Hi I'm trying to retrieve public tweets from twitter but it seems like there is no explanation for it. I have the below code but it's not working. Any idea if this is an outdated code and if you have any sample examples that I could have a look at would be much appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new MyTask().execute();

}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {

            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new
                    HttpGet("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=android");

            HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);

            if(rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
                JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray sessions = root.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i = 0; i < sessions.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject session = sessions.getJSONObject(i);

                    Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
                    tweet.content = session.getString("text");
                    tweet.author = session.getString("from_user");
                    tweets.add(tweet);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TwitterFeedActivity", "Error loading JSON", e);
        }
        return null;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        setListAdapter(new TweetListAdaptor(
                MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, tweets));
    }

}

private class TweetListAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {

    private ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;

    public TweetListAdaptor(Context context,

                            int textViewResourceId,
                            ArrayList<Tweet> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.tweets = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        Tweet o = tweets.get(position);

        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
        tt.setText(o.content);
        bt.setText(o.author);

        return v;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Always test your http methods independently of Android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35994186/7012517

Comment: Why don't you try Fabric twitter sdk https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

If you visit `http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=android` in a Web browser, you will see:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.","code":64}]}
```

> Any idea if this is an outdated code

Yes, it is, as the above error message indicates.

You can read [the Twitter REST API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public), such as [the documentation on their search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search).